# Use a variable, that is in a while loop, in an if statement python

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, while-loop

```
import datetime


time = datetime.datetime.now()
hm = 0

def function():

    while True:
        hm = (time.hour, time.minute)
        break

    if hm == (6,30):
        "stuff"
        function()

    else:
        "stuff"
```

My goal is to get the time and then do something once it reaches a certain time. My editor gives me an error saying the code is unreachable. I don't know what to do since I cannot return a variable in a while loop. Thanks.

Comment: While True makes an infinite loop, use a condition. OR use break, when necessary, I suggest a condition.

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Comment: You might want to try a library like [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: @Wyatt I'm going to go with your approach with schedule. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd skip the `while` loop and go with an approach more like this (if you don't want to use a library):

```
import datetime
import time

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
end_time = start_time.replace(hour=18, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta = end_time - start_time
time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
# do stuff
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sam Scolari/Documents/Python Projects/AndroidApp/service/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
ValueError: sleep length must be non-negative

Comment: You have to ensure that the end time is after the start time, possibly by adding 24 hours to the end time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any break statement in the Loop. The `if/else` is outside of the loop's scope. You need to indent it, and add some `break` statements.

Comment: With the edit I just made would the code repeat it's self like I wanted to then?